# Computational verification of Collatz conjecture

Tags: c, mathematics, integer, collatz-sequence

### Prerequisites

The `typedef` name `uint128_t` designates an unsigned integer type with width exactly 128 bits.

The `UINT128_MAX` is maximum value for an object of type `uint128_t`.

Function `int ctz(uint128_t n)` returns the number of trailing 0-bits in `n`, starting at the least significant bit position. If `n` is 0, the result is undefined.

The macro `UINT128_C(n)` shall expand to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type `uint128_t`.

The following macros are defined.

```
/* all 3^n for n < 41 fits into uint64_t */
#define LUT_SIZE64 41
/* all 3^n for n < 81 fits into uint128_t */
#define LUT_SIZE128 81
```

The following array is defined and initialized with corresponding values.

```
/* lut[n] contains 3^n */
uint128_t lut[LUT_SIZE128];
```

### Problem

My program is concerned with verifying the convergence of the [Collatz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), using [this algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330085/computational-verification-of-collatz-problem).

The convergence for all values `n` ≤ 87 × 2<sup>60</sup> has been proven. [Source: Christian Hercher, Uber die Lange nicht-trivialer Collatz-Zyklen, Artikel in der Zeitschrift "Die Wurzel" Hefte 6 und 7/2018.]

The following function is called for `n` of the form \$4n+3\$, in order from the smallest one to the largest one, only if all preceding calls returned zero.

The following function should either

- return 0 if the Collatz problem for the `n` is convergent,
- return 1 if the function cannot verify the convergence using 128-bit arithmetic,
- loop infinitely if the trajectory for the `n` is cyclic.

### Code

```
int check_convergence(uint128_t n)
{
    uint128_t n0 = n;
    int e;

    do {
        if (n <= UINT128_C(87) << 60) {
            return 0;
        }

        n++;

        e = ctz(n);

        n >>= e;

        if (n < UINT128_C(1) << 64 && e < LUT_SIZE64) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (n > UINT128_MAX >> 2*e || e >= LUT_SIZE128) {
            return 1;
        }

        n *= lut[e];

        n--;

        n >>= ctz(n);

        if (n < n0) {
            return 0;
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Comment: `n++;` & `n *= lut[e];`: Do you know for sure than none of those can overflow?  If not, you need to add a check for those.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Good point. The `n++` can overflow for initial `n = UINT128_MAX`. However, `n++` in subsequent iterations of the do-while loop cannot overflow since those immediately preceding `n >>= ctz(n);` will always make room for at least one bit.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito The `n *= lut[e];` cannot overflow since the condition `n > UINT128_MAX >> 2*e` ensures the result of that multiplication will surely fit the `uint128_t type`.

Comment: Actually, if `ctz(n) == 0`, it wouldn't shift, and therefore it wouldn't prevent overflow.  However, just before that, there is `n--;`, which would do so.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito `ctz(n)` is always greater than 0 since the argument `n` is even.

Comment: Is there any known upper bound to the number of iterations so that if the function reaches that number of iterations you can return a non-zero value instead of looping forever?

Comment: Wha do you return 0 when `(n < UINT128_C(1) << 64 && e < LUT_SIZE64)`

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Basically, for inputs below 87 x 2^60, there is no iteration at all. On the other hand, for the numbers above this boundary, nobody knows the upper bound for the number of iterations.

Comment: @miracle173 This is because when the result of n*3^e, and thus also odd_part(n*3^e-1), fits the 64-bit unsigned long, it is surely less than 87*2^60. So we can immediately decide that the problem converges.

Comment: I don't know about the maths behind this algorithm, but by looking at it, I would say that if your input is restricted to `UINT128_MAX - 1`, no more than `UINT128 - 1` iterations will be needed for convergence.  If there were more iterations, some number would have been repeated, which would mean we're in a loop.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Yes, unfortunately you cannot do `UINT128_MAX - 1` iterations on contemporary computers (and computers in the near or far future).

Comment: I have to say that I never tried, but why would it be impossible?  Is it because of time?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Lets say we have 3 GHz CPU computing 3 000 000 000 simple instructions per second. Then going over 2^128 states would roughly take 3.6 x 10^21 years.

Comment: Good to read that;  sometimes I tend to forget the most basic things :-)

Comment: I am not so firm in C but I think you check if if n<2^64 and e<41. But if n~2^64 and e=40  then n*3^e-1~ 2^64* 3^40 ~ 2^128, so the odd part of n*3^e-1 may be about 2^127., which is much higher than  87*2^60

Comment: @miracle173 Yes, this is a bug in the program. I will fix it...

Comment: @miracle173 I decided to remove this condition altogether. Is it correct now?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Vogel612 OK, no problem here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that (from your comments) there is one and only one input which would cause overflow, I propose the following check at the beginning of the function:

```
int check_convergence(uint128_t n)
{
        const uint128_t n0 = n;
        int e;

        if (n == UINT128_MAX)
                return  1;

        do {
                ...
        } while (true);
}
```

---

I also added `const` to `n0`, given that it's constant through all the function.

---

```
if (n < UINT128_C(1) << 64 && e < LUT_SIZE64)
        return  0;
```

That can be rewritten as:

```
if (n <= UINT64_MAX && e < LUT_SIZE64)
        return  0;
```

---

Although maybe unneeded, I prefer to always parenthesize macros that evaluate to a value, just in case:

```
#define LUT_SIZE128  (81)
```

Comment: `(unsigned long)(n>>64) == 0` seems to be much faster than `n < UINT128_C(1) << 64` or `n <= UINT64_MAX`.

Comment: @DaBler Nice. Even with `-O3` or `-Ofast` ?  Does the cast affect performance (in theory it is unneeded)?  I would remove that cast, or use `uint64_t` instead if it affects performance.

Comment: Using `-march=native -O3` and gcc 4.6.3 (`-Ofast` should only have effect on floating-point math, right?). The `(unsigned long)(n>>64) == 0` gives speedup factor about 1.1 over `n < UINT128_C(1) << 64`, depending on the particular input range.

Comment: @DaBler Curious. I guess GCC doesn't know how to optimize `unsigned __int128` very much, which is what I guess you are using for the `typedef`. I guess `n <= UINT64_MAX` is also slower. There's some other thing you may try, but which relies on implementation defined behaviour: Use a `union` that contains a `uint128_t` and a `uint64_t [2]`, and test which of the two elements of the array contains the MSbits. Then just compare that element of the union to `0`. It may be even faster than your shift, or it may not. Just try ;-)

Comment: That's exactly what I've tried for a few days back. But it did not bring any acceleration over mere `uint128_t`. See my attempt [here](https://github.com/xbarin02/collatz/blob/058030913c382b0e0a59a1cee7e80f5a2bd2c51a/collatz_enum.c) Look for `typedef union {
 unsigned long ul[2];
 uint128_t ull;
} uint128_u;`

Comment: @DaBler I'm curious about why you use `unsigned long` instead of the `<stdint.h>` types.

Comment: It is because I use libgmp. The problem with gmplib is that it does not support `uintN_t`. It only supports standard C types like `unsigned int`: https://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Integers.html#Assigning-Integers