# Computational verification of Collatz conjecture using gmplib

Tags: c, mathematics, integer, collatz-sequence

### Prerequisites

The `unsigned long` type has a size of 64 bits.

The following macros are defined.

```
/* all 3^n for n < 41 fits into 64-bit unsigned long */
#define LUT_SIZE 41
/* any reasonably high number */
#define LUT_SIZEMPZ 512
```

The following array is defined and properly initialized with corresponding values.

```
/* lut[n] contains 3^n */
mpz_t lut[LUT_SIZEMPZ];
```

Additionally, the following auxiliary function is defined.

```
/* count trailing zeros */
mp_bitcnt_t mpz_ctz(const mpz_t n)
{
    return mpz_scan1(n, 0);
}
```

### Problem

This code review request follows my previous request [Computational verification of Collatz conjecture](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226835/computational-verification-of-collatz-conjecture). The implementation in this request should handle the numbers which cannot be handled with the code in previous post.

In short: My program verifies the convergence of the [Collatz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), using [this algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330085/computational-verification-of-collatz-problem). The convergence for all values `n` ≤ 87 × 2<sup>60</sup> has already been proven.

The following function is called for `n` of the form \$4n+3\$, in order from the smallest one to the largest one, only if all preceding calls returned zero.

This function should either

- return `0` if the problem for the `n` is convergent, or
- loop infinitely if the trajectory for the `n` is cyclic.

## Code

The 128-bit input `n` is split into two 64-bit parts `nh` and `nl` such that `n = nh * 2^64 + nl`.

```
int check_convergence(unsigned long nh, unsigned long nl)
{
    mpz_t n;
    mpz_t n0;
    mpz_t n_max;
    mp_bitcnt_t e;

    mpz_init_set_ui(n, nh);
    mpz_mul_2exp(n, n, (mp_bitcnt_t)64);
    mpz_add_ui(n, n, nl);

    mpz_init_set_ui(n_max, 87UL);
    mpz_mul_2exp(n_max, n_max, (mp_bitcnt_t)60);

    mpz_init_set(n0, n);

    do {
        if (mpz_cmp(n, n_max) <= 0) {
            mpz_clear(n);
            mpz_clear(n0);
            mpz_clear(n_max);
            return 0;
        }

        mpz_add_ui(n, n, 1UL);

        e = mpz_ctz(n);

        mpz_fdiv_q_2exp(n, n, e);

        assert( e < LUT_SIZEMPZ );

        mpz_mul(n, n, lut[e]);

        mpz_sub_ui(n, n, 1UL);

        mpz_fdiv_q_2exp(n, n, mpz_ctz(n));

        if (mpz_cmp(n, n0) < 0) {
            mpz_clear(n);
            mpz_clear(n0);
            mpz_clear(n_max);
            return 0;
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a type with exactly 64 bits, use `uint64_t` (from `<stdint.h>`).  That will give a clear compilation error if no such type is available.

Given that the function never returns anything other than zero, we can move the cleanup of `n`, `n0` and `n_max` outside the loop, and simply `break` to reach them.

Is indefinite looping really a good output if a cycle is detected?  How is that distinguishable from an arbitrarily long (but finite) chain?  Look up the standard algorithms for cycle detection in your graph theory textbook.

Comment: The problem with gmplib is that it does not support `uint64_t`. It only supports standard C types like `unsigned int`: https://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Integers.html#Assigning-Integers

Comment: The program is part of distributed computing project. I cannot distinguish these two situations. I can however focus on particular assignments that have not been returned for a long time or that have not been returned from several different nodes.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `uint64_t` even if the API asks for an `unsigned long`.  It's far more precise about what it is, and you can always ensure that both are the same.

Assuming your C version is >= GNU C11 you can use the following code just below your `#include`s (actually anywhere, but I like it on top):

```
_Static_assert(__builtin_types_compatible_p(uint64_t, unsigned long),
                                           "uint64_t != unsigned long");
```

This code doesn't need to go inside a function.

If you just have C99 (Edit: GNU C99), you can do something similar:

```
#if (sizeof(uint64_t) != sizeof(unsigned long))
#error "uint64_t != unsigned long"
#endif
```

You could even write your own wrapper around GMP functions that uses `<stdint.h>` types.

If for whatever reason `unsigned long` changed suddenly to `uint32_t` or `uint128_t`, you would notice, instead of having new bugs everywhere.

Comment: I have received similar feedback through github today. I'll make over wrappers for ligmp functions. Anyhow, I use the C89 standard (+ GNU extensions), but it shouldn't matter so much. You should be however aware of that the `#if (sizeof(uint64_t) != sizeof(unsigned long))` is compiler extension. The C preprocessor does not know the unary operator `sizeof`. The fact that these constructs work is just due to extensions of compilers.

Comment: Anyway, good feedback.

Comment: @DaBler Yes, it was me in GitHub :p

Comment: @DaBler Good to know that about `sizeof`. I thought it was standard.  I found this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4079243/6872717

Comment: I posted a comment in GitHub to you...